# Logging to single file from multiple processes: why it works?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is an excerpt from the [Python Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html):

> Although logging is thread-safe, and logging to a single file from
>   multiple threads in a single process is supported, **logging to a single
>   file from multiple processes is not supported**, because there is no
>   standard way to serialize access to a single file across multiple
>   processes in Python.

However, I made a simple program that has multiple processes logging to a single file and I would like to understand why it works and when should I expect it to fail.

Following is the module logger that I am using:

```
import os
import logging
from datetime import datetime

def get_logger(name):
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M')
    logging.basicConfig(filename=f'{timestamp}.log', filemode='w',
                    style='{', level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='{asctime}\t{name}\t{levelname}\t{message}')
    return logging.getLogger(name)
```

And here is an example of how I use it to log info throughout my program:

```
import time
import random
import multiprocessing

from logger import get_logger

def function_1_that_logs(i):
    for i in range(10):
        n = random.randint(0,5)
        logger.debug(f'process {i} sleeping for {n} seconds')
        time.sleep(n)

def function_2_that_logs(i):
    logger.info(f'simple log from process {i}')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    logger = get_logger(__file__)

    logger.info('started logging')

    pool1 = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    pool2 = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())

    for i in range(multiprocessing.cpu_count()):
        pool1.apply_async(function_1_that_logs, [i+1])
        pool2.apply_async(function_2_that_logs, [(i+1*2)])

    pool1.close()
    pool1.join()
    pool2.close()
    pool2.join()
    logger.info('finished logging')
```

I have already implemented a solution that apply a monkey patch to the `info`, `debug`, `warning` and `error` functions, where they can only work if they have access granted by a global mutex variable. However I still want to understand why this simple code works, even though the cookbook states the opposite. Is it because I am running on Linux and it creates processes using `fork`, and therefore, there is no need to serialize the logger object? Where can this naive solution fail?

Edit:

Here is the [output log](https://gist.github.com/alexandredias3d/a08b41d8c779790f414f74d97eab8f36) where everything was written and no errors occurred. I also have a 35MB log from the real program running and apparently everything is fine with it also.

Comment: and you've confirmed that only one log file is being written, and both statements make it into the one file?

Comment: I have edited the question with the output log. But yes, the log seems fine.

Comment: I think logger is not safe to use from multiple processes for the same reason it is not safe to write a file from multiple processes. Your program formats log records into application buffers passed to your system's standard library using it's own buffering. Then the kernel and file system drivers have their own buffering. Some filesystems are POSIX compliant and treat appends to files atomic, some others are not. Python has no way to control all those layers.

Comment: "Not supported" really means that the result cannot be garanteed and that one should not expect this to work reliably. It might work on some systems, or at least it might seem to work for some times until it breaks for whatever unpredictable reason.

Comment: this fails when we try rotating file handlers i.e for rolling logs